# Need help wiring a power supply to UK rocker switch

Tags: power-supply, power, switches

I'm looking to wire up the UK rocker switch/plug to a power supply. There's a black cable coming from the live & a red one coming from Neutral. I don't want to blow anything up so I'm looking for some help if someone can help me map which cables need to go where.

This is the power supply : https://gyazo.com/d00cdca931641a1a186160659f786d92?token=5072c9b33dbdfb7521bb23f5928c5532

Link to the actual product too: [www.aliexpress.com/item/32823738256.html](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/32823738256.html)

This is the rocker switch: https://gyazo.com/e9845e141a03c70d48ffc3660ae8b625 (front) & https://gyazo.com/d0aa7ef9711a9f78e43e238af10bea7f (back)

Comment: Red was live and Black was Neutral in the old UK code. (Green was Earth) And both were obsolete 40 years ago, probably closer to 50. Therefore you seem to be looking at something very old and dangerously miswired. (At least the photo shows something much newer, with L and N right way round).

Comment: https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32823738256.html - This is the item, it's being sold today - I have proper blue/brown/green&yellow cable if that's better to use, black & red is just what came with it. Can you offer any advice for me?

Comment: @BrianDrummond  IEC 60446 came law here in 2004 so you could still wire a house with red/black at least 20years ago and buy said cable 20years ago

Comment: Hey @JonRB, oh cool you live in Birmingham - me too! :) Can you help a fellow brummie out on this one ?

Comment: :) looking at the item in question, 99.9% confident that RED=Live and BLACK=Neutral (as per old colours, and equally convenient engineering practice). The frontend is either a rectifier and as such is functionally no different (but for safety it should be correct). Likewise look at the label on the PCB and the header: LIVE aligns with RED

Comment: Cool thanks @JonRB  - Would you be able to show me how the back should look? https://gyazo.com/d0aa7ef9711a9f78e43e238af10bea7f

I know there will need to be additional cables connecting elements on the prongs on the rocker switch in some way : https://gyazo.com/e9845e141a03c70d48ffc3660ae8b625 & what I'm confused about is how it all links up & whether I need a ground on there/need to connect the neutrals to light the led in the switch for example.

Comment: Note that the **FG** point is for Frame Ground, i.e. you need to connect that to the mains earth lead. With the price of that PSU, it would be prudent to also add an earth lead actually connected to the PSU case with a ring terminal on a screw. If you've got a friend who's an electrician, show him the bits and he'll make one for you for a pint.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thanks Andrew, appreciate you mentioning that, I really wasn't sure what that one. Unfortunately, I don't have any electrician friends, which is why I'm here, I know it's a big ask but if someone can sketch out some kind of diagram for me so I know how to wire it, it would be really appreciated! I'd be happy to sort a pint out too :D